# JupyterLab - install extensions with Extension Manager to user home dir separately

Tags: jupyter-lab

**JupyterLab** installed as root using: `/opt/jupyterhub/bin/python3`.

When i try to install some extension from **Extension Manager** interface i see error about **`no permissions to access /opt/jupyterhub/bin/python3.10/site-packages`**.. I know I can install extensions from command-line with sudo, but this is not solution, because in case installing extensions in system python which run Jupyter I will get extensions hell, when all users use same extensions. But will be good to setup JupyterLab to install extension to users home dirs and each user will have own extensions set.